# Given the adjacency matrix of weighted directed graph, how to draw such graph in Tikz without weights?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have the adjacency matrix for a directed weighted graph. I want to draw this graph in tikz. My adjacency matrix is of size 50 by 50 and I have it in txt format. Obviously it is better to have  code that uses the txt file and also positions the nodes automatically since I don't have the positions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Draw 50 nodes in a circle and connect them where necessary.

Comment: Having a 50 nodes graph would be pretty unlegible but anyway, it's possible. You may draw an edge wherever the weight is different from zero, so it's just a question of `\if ... \fi` but it's hard to help you without anything to start with. Please edit your post with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

Fifty nodes are going to be a mess but here's a start for nine.

For the real usage remove the line commented with `fake` and uncomment `real` which actually sets the weights given by the weights/matrix, e.g.

```
weights/matrix={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

for the 3×3 matrix

> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9

---

This is obviously not legible but I'm open for suggestions.
No rotation? White background? Line width? Dash pattern? Color?

With the `graphdrawing` library, maybe a better layout can be achieved, especially if a lot of edges have a weight of zero.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for \overset
\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs.standard, % for \graph and subgraph I_n
  quotes,          % "nodes" on edges
  ext.misc}        % for /utils/TeX/ifnum
\tikzset{
  weights/matrix/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\listrow{0},
    /utils/rows/.style={
      /utils/exec=\def\listcol{0}\edef\listrow{\the\numexpr\listrow+1\relax},
      /utils/cols/.estyle={/utils/exec=\edef\noexpand\listcol{\noexpand\the\numexpr\noexpand\listcol+1\relax},
        /tikz/weights/weight \listrow-\noexpand\listcol/.initial/.evaluated={random(0,9)}% fake
%        /tikz/weights/weight \listrow-\noexpand\listcol/.initial={####1}% real
      }, /utils/cols/.list={##1},
    }, /utils/rows/.list={#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  weights/matrix={% include actual weights here
    {,,,,,,,,},
    {,,,,,,,,},
    {,,,,,,,,},
    {,,,,,,,,},
    {,,,,,,,,},
    {,,,,,,,,},
    {,,,,,,,,},
    {,,,,,,,,},
    {,,,,,,,,}},
]
\graph [
  clockwise, % place nodes in a circle
  radius=5cm,% of this radius
  nodes={circle, draw},
  do edge/.style 2 args={
    % if the weight is 0 → ignore edge
    /utils/TeX/ifnum={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/weights/weight #1-#2}=0}{}{
      /utils/TeX/ifnum={#1=#2}{
        % if row = col → just add label
        parse={#1[label={[anchor=west]west:%
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/weights/weight #1-#2}}]}
      }{% otherwise draw edge and add weight as a label
        parse={#1 --[
          "$#1\overset{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/weights/weight #1-#2}}{\to}#2$"{
            sloped, allow upside down}] #2}}}}
]{
  subgraph I_n[n=9];
  {[
    /tikz/every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize, inner ysep=+.4ex},
    /tikz/every label/.append style={inner sep=+.1em},
  ] \foreach \row in {1,...,9} {
      \foreach \col in {1,...,9} {
        [do edge=\row\col]}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Of course, storing the matrix in value-keys isn't necessary, we can use them directly in the loops in the graphs. And with `pgfplotstable` we can use the loops provided by the package to loop over the rows and columns in an external file.